# Connecting django with oracle database

Tags: django, oracle

Im a beginner to django. 
Someone help to connect Oracle 11g db with django 2.0 in windows. What is the requirements and how to connect and what are the changes to be done.

Comment: lmgtfy: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/vasiliev-django-100257.html

Answer (score 2):

According [to the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#oracle-notes),

> Django supports Oracle Database Server versions 12.1 and higher. Version 5.2 or higher of the cx_Oracle Python driver is required.

You may run in to trouble with version 11g -- but if you want to give it a shot, that link has the instructions.